# Error when comparing 2 date column of dates

Tags: r

I created a new column `Date_flag` to compare the dates of `COL1` and `COL2` using the code  below.

But it showed that `5/1/15` is greater than `6/1/2014` and `5/1/2015` greater than `7/1/2014` despite the year is greater. How do I fix that?

I did try to format as `%y/%m/%d`  but it does not fix the problem.

```
data$Date_Flag <- ifelse(data$COL2 > data$COL1, 0,1)

  COL1       COL2
 6/1/14     5/1/15 
 7/1/14     5/1/15 

data$COL2<- as.Date(as.character(data$COL2, format="%y/%m/%d"))
data$COL1<- as.Date(as.character(data$COL1, format="%y/%m/%d"))
```

Comment: Did you type the question wrong?  2015 _is_ greater than 2014.

Comment: Check your years... from the information you've provided, it's working perfectly

Comment: Rather, check your `format`. And `format` is an argument of `as.Date`, not of `as.character`.

Comment: It shows 6/1/2014 and 7/1/2014 as greater.

Comment: Still does not work when I changed to format to as.Date only

Comment: the format should be `"%m/%d/%y"`